# "The server tag is not well formed." What's wrong?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I get the following parser error message. How can I fix this problem?

> The server tag is not well formed.

Code:

```
<a href="#" class="mySprite id<%# ((int)DataBinder.Eval(Container,"ItemIndex")) % 6 + 1%>">
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

First of all, your anchor is client side, you should add an attribute of `runat="server"` to this. Second, try using it like following.

```
<a href="#" runat="server" id="mySprite1" 
class='<%# "mySprite id" + ((int)DataBinder.Eval(Container,"ItemIndex")) % 6 + 1 %>'>
```

Comment: do I need to give single quotes or something ?

Comment: you do not need `runat="server"`, as long as you do not work with the html-control on a databound-event (or for the associatedControl-property of a label)!

Comment: @Andreas::Yes I know..thnx...@Zain :: Single quotes were missing..it's resolved now..thnx

Answer (score 1):

It might be helpful to review the difference in expressions: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dancre/archive/2007/02/13/the-difference-between-lt-and-lt-in-asp-net.aspx

The `runat="server"` is only needed for databinding.

So, use the `<%= %>` syntax instead.  Also make sure your quotes aren't getting mixed up, so use `'` for the outer one and `"` for the inner ones.